# References from a project to another version of other in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, version-control

I'm developing an java web application using Eclipse IDE. I have configured version control with mercurial server and all my projects have a mercurial version.

Suppose I have an application "A" that compiles to a jar library and I want to maintain one version for production and other for development.
Suppose I have another application "B" that uses A clasess, but I want to use production version of A when I compile "B" to production and development version of A in others cases.

If in A and B project I have a branch with production version and development version, and in B project I have reference to A project to use libraries, how can specify to eclipse project B that I want to user production version of A or not?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a dependency management system like [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/).  Eclipse has good support for it.

Answer (score 0):

Link to Project A as a "Java Project", not the JAR produced by Project A.  Then, when you check out your Dev branch, you get the Dev version of A, but when you check out your Prod branch, you get your Prod version.

Alternatively, if you are using something like Maven, you could put your Prod and "SNAPSHOT" Jars in a Maven Repo, and simply modify your pom.xml in your Dev branch to pull the SNAPSHOT version of your JAR.